# Present View within UITabBarController & UINavigationController Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

We are working on an iOS app, which has a RootVC, where 4 TABs placed programmatically, each Tab has a separate `ViewController`. One of the Tabs responsible for search. When the user taps the search button on this specific `ViewController`, we'd like to present the search results in another `ViewController`, which has the `TabBar` at the bottom and the `NavigationController` at the top with a "Back" button. 
How can I achieve this? I tried with `self.navigationController?.present`, push, but none of them worked.

RootVC.swift:

```
class RootVC: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTabBarLayout()

    }

    private func setupTabBarLayout() {
        // 1. Profile page
        let profileVC = ProfileVC()
        let profileVCBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Profil", image: UIImage(named: "profile_icon"), tag: 1)
        profileVC.tabBarItem = profileVCBarItem

        // 2. Search
        let searchVC = SearchVC()
        let searchVCBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Search", image: UIImage(named: "search_icon"), tag: 2)
        searchVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        searchVC.tabBarItem = searchVCBarItem

        // 3. Meet
        let meetVC = MeetVC()
        let meetVC = SearchResultsVC()
        let meetVCBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Meet", image: UIImage(named: "meet_icon"), tag: 3)
        meetVC.tabBarItem = meetVCBarItem

        // 4. Activities
        let activitiesVC = ActivitiesVC()
        let activitiesVCBarITem = UITabBarItem(title: "Activities", image: UIImage(named: "activities_icon"), tag: 4)
        activitiesVC.tabBarItem = activitiesVCBarITem

        // VC Setup
        viewControllers = [profileVC, searchVC, meetVC, activitiesVC]
        // Design settings
        self.tabBar.backgroundColor = .lightButtonBg
        self.tabBar.barTintColor = .darkMagenta
        self.tabBar.tintColor = .customWhite
        self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .lightButtonBg
        self.tabBar.isTranslucent = false

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Julian. Unfortunately it drops an error:
"Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifierForStoryboard

navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

and then observe if there is an error like view not in hierarchy

Comment: Thanks, but we don't use storyboard.
Anyway, with this code, the navigation controller becomes visible with a back button, but tabBar is missing at the bottom.

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SearchResultsVC(), animated: true)

Comment: Should I use UITabBarControllerDelegate?

Comment: I think this might be it i have implemented it myself:  using an array of controllers:--https://medium.com/@ITZDERR/uinavigationcontroller-and-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically-swift-3-d85a885a5fd0

Comment: Thanks Mayank, that's what I'm looking for!

Comment: no worries man happy to help. A small favour would you please upvote

Comment: A little addition to the topic:
Subclass UINavigationController:

class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Your customization code goes here...
        navigationBar.barTintColor = .magenta
        let titleAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleAttribute
        navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    }
}
Then use it within TabBar
let firstVC = CustomNavigationController(rootViewController: FirstVC())